# CakePHP Prefixing All Relative Path Links with /app/webroot/index.php/

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, routes, cakephp-2.0

I'm using Cake 2.0.6 and for some reason on every page (aside from my home page) all of my links with relative paths are being prefixed with: `/app/webroot/index.php/`.

I'm thinking it's either a routes issue or possibly a mod_rewrite issue with my .htaccess files, but I followed the information from: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html#apache-and-mod-rewrite-and-htaccess

Per someone's suggestion in my DocumentRoot for my VirtualHost settings I appended `app/webroot` to it, but that just made all the relative links relative to the url of the page they were on.

Anyone ever had this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I needed to replace the last line of my .htaccess file in `/app/webroot` from:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

The `?` made all the difference. Weird it wasn't included like that by default though.